# HOW TO FIGURE RESISTOR WATTAGE

Tags: resistors, resistance

I am trying to understand how to figure a resistors wattage based on label.[image]

[image]

Comment: This is manufacturer-specific marking. You go to their website, find the catalog/datasheet and look for the "ordering information" or similar section describing the markings format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the part number into your search engine and hope to get a result, preferably a manufacturer data sheet for the given part series.

For the Ohmite part 210-100M-40, you will find that it is a 50 ohm 100W part.

Comment: thankyou I am having a hard time figuring out part name from  part number  right now. I am new at this.